# setting a string array size to the size of another string

Tags: java, arrays, string

Can any explain to me how to set a string array size to the size of an existing string similar to a .length when using ints. For instance if my string variable was String str = "Banana"; I would want my string array to be of size 6 but without using the number use, I would like to use the length version. I am a newer programmer and for some reason cannot find anything like this in my programming book or on this website.

Comment: `String[] array = new String[str.length()];`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Java API documentation for class `String` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you notice that it provides method `length()`:

`public int length​()` - *returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.*

You can use that method to initialize array with the value that is returned from that method:

```
String yourString = "banana";
String[] resultArray = new String[yourString.length()]; // declares array of length equal to 6
```